# Randomized Quick Sort Pivot selection with 25%-75% split

Tags: algorithm, big-o, quicksort, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

I came to know that in case of Randomized quick sort, if we choose the pivot in such a way that it will at least give the split in the ration 25%-75%, then the run time is `O(n log n)`.
Now I also came to know that we can prove this with Master Theorem.

But my problem is that if we split the array in 25%-75% in each step, then how I will define my `T(n)` and how can I prove that the runtime analysis in `O(n log n)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to find the complexity of this kind of algorithms. In this particular case assume, that when you divide the array into two parts each of these parts is not greater then 3/4 of the initial array. Then, `T(n) < 2 * T(3/4 * n) + O(n)`, or `T(n) = 2 * T(3/4 * n) + O(n)` if you look for upper bound. Master theorem gives you the solution for this equation.

**Update:** though Master theorem may solve such recurrence equations, in this case it gives us a result which is worse than expected O(n*log n). Nevertheless, it can be solved in other way. If we assume that a pivot always splits the array in the way that the smaller part is >= 1/4 size, then we can limit the recursion depth as log_{4/3}N (because on each level the size of array decreases by at least 4/3 times). Time complexity on each recursion level is O(n) in total, thus we have O(n) * log{4/3}n = O(n*log n) overall complexity.

Furthermore, if you want some more strict analysis, you may consider a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) article, there are some good proofs.

Comment: Hi Ivan,Thanks for your response. But as per T(n) < 2 * T(3/4 * n) + O(n), the values are a=2, b=4/3, d=1. So it means a>b^d. So T(n) =O(n^log a [base b]). But T(n) should be O(nlogn). Could you please tell me how I can prove that? Thanks

Comment: @SudiptaDeb Oops, sorry, I've forgotten Master theorem a bit. Here is an updated solution.